# Making a binary Calc in C#

Tags: c#

I am making a binary calc where you can enter a binary number and the program will output the dezimal number. The Script looks like this:

[Binary Code Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u57c29)

First I get the User input, then I reverse it because i will need to calc the numbers( 0 and 1s) backwards in the loop later on. Lets say I will input the Binary number 10 (2 in dezimal) in. First the loop will multiply 0 by 2 abd then multiply it by the power of 0. Then it will raise the "power multiplier" by 1. Now its going on again for 1 it will basicly do 1x2^1 again. At the end of the loop it always adds the calcutated summary to the var erg to output it later to the user. Somehow, as soon as i input something higher 1 it outputs the wrong calculated dezimal number. Is the variable type wrong or is the calculation wrong?

Comment: Code should be in the question itself as a [mcve]. Links will rot over time, making the question less useful to future visitors with the same problem as you. Thanks.

Comment: `BigInteger decimalValue = binaryValue.Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (s, a) => s * 2 + a - '0');`

Comment: If you are wondering why the code in the answers doesn't reverse the digits, consider a string to decimal number converter. For example `"1234"`. Loop over the digits. Start with `1`. Is there another digit, if so, multiple things by 10 and add in the new digit (getting `12`). Is there another digit, yup, multiply by 10 (giving `120`) and add in that `3`. Is there another digit, yup, giving `1234`. Is there another digit, nope, `1234` it is.

Comment: Indeed, processing left to right and multiplying by the base each time automatically upgrades the accumulating number to the necessary power

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that .net can already do this conversion

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(binaryString, 2); //base 2
```

Answer (score 0):

When having a *binary* `input` you can obtain *decimal* `result` in one line with a help of *Linq*.

To convert binary, say, `111010` into decimal one can use loop with `+` and `*`:

```
111010 => ((((1 * 2 + 0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1
```

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

...

BigInteger result = input.Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (s, a) => s * 2 + a - '0');
```

In case you prefer good old *loop* (no *Linq* solution):

```
BigInteger result = 0;

foreach(char c in input)
  result = result * 2 + c - '0';
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TsUcEf)